# PHP Date Formats

Tags: php

This should be simple, but I'm having trouble... so turn to StackOverflow...

I'm in the UK and am getting a date from the jQuery DatePicker in a dd/mm/yy format.
I want to store this date as a serial (yyyymmdd) so run a Date_To_Serial function that just does:

```
return date("Ymd", strtotime($strDate_In));
```

where $strDate_In is the date string in dd/mm/yy format.

So, passing in 01/12/2013, I expect 20131201 to be returned.

But, when 01/12/2013 is passed in, it returns 20130112 - PHP obviously assumes the date format is mm/dd/yyyy.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: @JezB : Hello friend, date picker provide to set  the format of date. So if you choose Ymd there then i think you will not get the problem again. Try it

Comment: @JezB : Please see http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the format, try using the static createFromFormat method on the `DateTime` class:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/12/2013');
return $date->format('Ymd');
```

Comment: Thank you - I knew someone would know very quickly!

Answer (score 1):

If the separator is a `/` then [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) assumes a US-format. To have it recognise a UK format the separator must be `-` or `.`:

```
echo date('Ymd', strtotime('01/12/2014')); // 20140112
echo date('Ymd', strtotime('01-12-2014')); // 20141201
```

So for this to work in your example you would do:

```
return date("Ymd", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $strDate_In)));
```

Comment: "f the separator is a / then strtotime assumes a US-format. To have it recognise a UK format the separator must be - or .:" - I didn't know that... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DateTime` object's **[`createFromFormat` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)**. It allows you to specify the format of the input.

Afterwards, use the **`format`** method to export the date in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) for correct handling of non-standard date formats.

```
return DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $strDate_In)->format("Ymd");
```